# How to fill a 2D array with a result from division of 2 random numbers in 2 different ranges but the result being in certain range?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I need to fill a 2D array with result from division of 2 random numbers in 2 different ranges but the result can't be in range (-2,2). Ranges of two random numbers are (-15,5) and (-2,2). When I Compile & Run the program it it does not work properly. It outputs just a few lines or nothing and finishes itself. I am using Dev-C++.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main() {

int array[11][11];
int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
int res = 0;
srand(time(NULL));  
for (int i = 0;i < 11;i++) {
    for (int j = 0;j < 11;j++) {
        do {
            num1 = (rand() % (5 + 15 + 1)) - 15;
            num2 = (rand() % (2 + 2 + 1)) - 2;
            res = num1 / num2;
            printf("%d/%d=%d\t", num1, num2, res);

        } while (res >= -2 && res <= 2);
        array[i][j] = res;
        printf("\narray[%d][%d]=%d",i,j, array[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Ouput:

```
-15/-1=15
array[0][0]=15
-2/2=-1 5/-2=-2 1/1=1   -13/1=-13
array[0][1]=-13
-6/-2=3
array[0][2]=3
-12/1=-12
array[0][3]=-12

--------------------------------
Process exited after 4.478 seconds with return value 3221225620
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: There's no protection against "division by zero" (mathematically impossible.) Try ensuring that `num2` is not used if its value is 0.

Comment: And what is the exit code? No error message was printed? Because you have 20% chance to have a division by 0 with your code. It is not surprising that you have 4 working lines and then an error (even tho it is random, so you could have started with an error at the first line, or, on the contrary, drawn 10 working lines before the error

Comment: @Fe2O3 to be precise, dividing by 0 is impossible if the x (as in x / 0) is different from 0. If x happens to be 0 as well, then we have 0 / 0 = p, therefore 0 * p = 0, which is true for any p. Hence, 0 / 0 could result in any number, whereas x / 0 is impossible if x differs from 0.

Comment: TheDegman, "Ranges of two random numbers are ... (-2,2)" is a bit unclear.  `[]` typical means to include the end-points: -2,-1, 0,1,,2. `()` means to exclude the endpoints: -1, 0,1.  Please clearly state your coding goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You need to avoid [dividing with 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero). Let's change your `do`-`while` to the following:

```
        do {
            num1 = (rand() % (5 + 15 + 1)) - 15;
            num2 = (rand() % (2 + 2 + 1)) - 2;
            res = (num2 != 0) ? (num1 / num2) : 0; //we default to 0 if the division was with 0
            printf("%d/%d=%d\t", num1, num2, res);

        } while (res >= -2 && res <= 2);
```